# AWK - "for loop" inside of new line print

Tags: awk

I'm searching how to put for loop inside "print" - I've managed how to get all information what I need from log file but if I use "for loop" after print then each new information is given in new line. I know that is calling print each time so... how to print all in new line?
For example this:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/domlogs/xxxx/xxxx.com* | awk -F " " '{print $1 " - " $4 " " $5 " "} {for(i=12; i<=NF; i++) print $i}'
```

Give me that output:

```
66.249.65.172 - [29/May/2019:02:48:20 +0200]
"Mozilla/5.0
(compatible;
Googlebot/2.1;
+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

But when I want to pass at end what I found between 12 col and NF:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/domlogs/xxxx/xxxx.com* | awk -F " " '{print $1 " - " $4 " " $5 " " for(i=12; i<=NF; i++) " " $i}'
```

Then I get only:

```
66.249.65.172 - [29/May/2019:02:48:20 +0200]
```

I'm heading to output like:

```
66.249.65.172 - [29/May/2019:02:48:20 +0200] "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `printf()` over `print` because the latter by default embeds a newline after the string provided. Modify your code to use `printf` with format specifiers for each of the strings.

```
awk '{ printf "%s - %s  %s ", $1, $4, $5 } 
     { for(i=12; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s ", $i; printf "\n" }'
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that's did the trick - only I've added extra space here `"%s - %s  %s "` because output had lack of it